# Ubuntu 17.04 freezes

Tags: libreoffice, repository, freeze

I was navigating on Internet, had rythmbox reading a song and LibreOffice open developing a chart when suddenly on Firefox all freezed  and a ahotdown and reboot was necessary.

For all the similar cases, in particular a had a repository file missing, so I guess this was reason, I've removed both repository files missing 10 min after dealing with freezed ubuntu.

Best regards!

Answer (score -1):

The reason behind this may be that you are not running a stable Os version and Ubuntu 17 has a lot of bugs and even the LTS version is not released so I prefer that you must downgrade your Ubuntu to 16.04 LTS as it is having really less bugs and I am also currently using it and there has been no issues since then.

There may be other Reasons like :-

Incorrect Installation

Drivers Fault

But I insist that you should downgrade your version to 16.04 LTS

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 is stable. Don't recommend downgrade to 16.04 LTS unless you can point out explicit problems that can be worked around by downgrading.